# Adding if validates in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-5

I search a solution to require several selections of response (3),
whitout "check_must_be_3" I do not have problem.
If I add this solution, I have a rollback.
This is my idea but it seems not to be working!

model.rb:

```
validates :check, presence: true
validate :check_must_be_3

  private
    def checks_must_be_3
      if !check != 3
        errors[:base] << "You must select exactly 3 checks"
      end
    end
```

html:

```
<%= simple_form_for @answer do |f| %>
  <h3>Choose 3 answers</h3>
    <ul>
    <% (1..5).each do |x| %>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="answer[check][]" id="optionsCheckbox<%= x %>" value="<%= x %>" />
          <%= x %>
        </label>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
private

def answer_params
    params.require(:answer).permit(check:[])
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#try this
    private
    def checks_must_be_3
      unless check.count == 3
        errors.add(:base , "You must select exactly 3 checks")
      end
    end
```

Comment: Thanks, I have this error:    wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1+)